# Objective-C cocoapod bridging issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Followed this to a t:

https://medium.com/@kirualex/cocoapods-with-swift-e6f8ba8f0afc

Can't find these 2 header files though.

Set the bridging file in the settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I always meet this kind of problem. I think you can try to check your file&folder hierarchy.

Such as you have a root folder named Project, as is often the case, there is another Project in your previous Project, the root folder.

And Checking the Objective-C Bridging Header in the Build Setting. Sometime error can occurred for Project/Project/Bridging-Header.h. And the error can be corrected by changing the definition as Project/Bridging-Header.h.

If the location of Bridging-Header.h is not matching with the definition in the Build Setting, the error like import file not found will occur.

I just tell your my solution for Bridging issue I already met, I hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks Ethan, had to add to the user search path , Pods/Headers/Public and change the declaration in the bridging file to: #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "SimpleAuth/SimpleAuth.h"